# ng-if validator not working properly

Tags: cordova, ng-show, angular-ng-if, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-show

I'm trying to show a phrase using ng-if / ng-show (with less or bigger than condition) validator but its not working 100% correct.
Here's my code:

```
<p style="color: #fff; text-align: center; margin-top: 3px;" ng-hide="coin.cant_coin > '49'" > No enough cash!</p>
```

Here's my problem:

It works perfect from 50 to 99 but from 100 and bigger numbers its not working.
I noticed that if I change value from 49 to 149 it works okay from 149 to 999 but stop working from 50 to 99.
Same thing happens with ng-show and ng-hide.
What could it be? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you have apostrophes around 49?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your problem is not the validator but your expression.

What type is coin.cant_coin? Is it an integer? Or is it a string?

If your input is: 100 > 49, it works.
However, if your input is: '100' > '49', then it doesn't work.

I created a Plunker, which shows you the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/OJfGD3XqE4YG5DgFlXwt?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">

Input: 100 > 49
<br>
<div ng-hide="100 > 49" > Works properly.</div><br>

Input: '100' > '49'<br>
<br>
<div ng-hide="'100' > '49'" > ERROR!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, after I posted the question I noticed that I shouldn't use the apostrophes. But I mark yours as correct cause is the properly correction. Thank you guys!!